# Botocore previous versions documentation

Tags: boto3

Is it possible to read the documentation of previous versions? Tried it, looked for answers but no success so far.

http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://github.com/boto/botocore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no hosted documentation for previous versions, no. You can, however, generate the docs yourself and view them locally if you wish. Below are the steps to do so, which I would recommend doing inside a temporary virtual environment.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/boto/botocore.git
$ cd botocore
$ git checkout $RELEASE_COMMIT
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ pip install -r requirements-docs.txt
$ pip install -e .
$ cd docs
$ make html
$ open build/html/index.html
```

You can easily find the release commits [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/releases).

Comment: Keep in mind this will downgrade botocore on your system too

Answer (score 9):

As of 2018-10-04, the link http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ mentioned in the question is redirecting to https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html.

You can access the previous version of documentation by replacing `{version_number}` with the version you want visit in the following URL.
`https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/{version_number}/index.html`

For example, visit https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.12.19/index.html for version 1.12.19 documentation.

Please note, as of 2022-10-20, documentation is available only for versions >= **1.10.50**